# Joining two sets in SAS SQL with table/correlation error

Tags: sas

I am trying to join two datasets. The first dataset1 has two columns item and price. The second dataset2 has three columns - item, customerid, and qty. I need to only include the unique rows from dataset1 that are not in dataset2. While trying to implement this code, I get the error:

Error: Unresolved reference to table/correlation name i.

I am unsure how to fix this error, thanks.

```
PROC SQL;

create table a as

select *
    from dataset1 as i

except corr

select *
    from dataset2 as p 

where i.item = p.item;

describe table a;

QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXCEPT` is used to select records in the first set that do not exist in the second set. So if what you want is, to quote you, select **records** from `dataset1` that do not appear in `dataset2`, you don't need the `where` clause:

```
PROC SQL;
create table a as
select *
    from dataset1 as i
except corr
select *
    from dataset2 as p 
;
QUIT;
```

If however, like that `where` clause would suggest, you actually want to select records from `dataset1` where the value of `item` is not found in `dataset2`, you could do this

```
proc sql;
select *
from dataset1 i
where not exists (select *
                 from dataset2 p
                 where i.item=p.item
                )
;
quit;
```

**EDIT:** following your latest comment, and if you *reaaaally* need your query to feature an `except`, this should get you your result

```
proc sql;
create table a as
select t1.*
from dataset1 t1
inner join (select *
            from dataset1 as i
            except corr
            select *
            from dataset2 as p
           ) t2
on t1.item=t2.item  
;
quit;
```

Even though this will do the same as the query above (with `not exists`) or, now that I think of it (stupid me), as this:

```
proc sql;
  create table a as
  select *
  from dataset1
  where item not in (select distinct item from dataset2)
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: I am supposed to do this using set operators like except, union, intersect. Except seems to be the right thing to use here but not sure

Comment: @Ami well then did you try my first suggestion?

Comment: Hi, yes I did. It works but only displays one column - the unique items from dataset1 not in 2.However, it does not include customerid, price, or quantity. @user2877959

Comment: @Ami so I take it your two datasets do not have the same structure? (i.e. same columns with same names)? Also, why are you _"supposed to do this using set operators"_?

Comment: So the first data set has two columns, item and price. Second data set has three columns, item customerid and qty. Since the second data set includes quantity, it is a dataset of items actually purchased. I need to merge the dataset so that the final table shows the items that were not purchased, but also their price. The assignment is based on a set operator lesson. I am not familiar with using where not exists.

Comment: @Ami Does not being familiar with `where not exists` mean that you can't use it or that it will not work? Also, you explain that you want to see a list of items that were _not purchased_ along with their price. However in your previous comment you mentioned that my solution did not display `customerid` and `quantity`. It seems strange to me to want to display who did not purchase the item and how many of the item they did not purchase...?